# CATALINA_PID != real PID

Tags: java, tomcat, pid, catalina

I set:

```
$ export CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.pid"
```

Started **Tomcat**:

```
$ ./bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.53
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.53
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/conf/catalina.pid
Tomcat started.
```

Checked pid-file:

```
$ cat /home/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/conf/catalina.pid
28461
```

But - there is no process `28461`:

```
$ ps aux | grep 28461
tomcats  28599  0.0  0.0 103240   872 pts/0    S+   12:50   0:00 grep 28461

$ ps -p 28461
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

And Tomcat's JVM runs with other PID:

```
$ ps u | grep tomcat | grep java | grep -v grep | cut -d" " -f 3
30133
```

From "*Tomcat the Definitive Guide*" of *Jason Brittain* book we know that:

> CATALINA_PID This variable may optionally hold the path to the process ID file
>   that Tomcat should use when starting up and shutting down.
>   None

Use:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

So, question is: for what exactly `CATALINA_PID` variable needs or - why it's return wrong number?

Close question - after few restarts/kills it is now works good... Don't know why.

Comment: > So - for what exactly CATALINA_PID variable needs or - why it's return wrong number? // sorry, it is not "real question"? and about blog - I just pass all info, which I have, to to give a complete picture.

Comment: The purpose is for the file in CATALINA_PID to contain the pid of tomcat. If that's not happening, there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: I have tested your scenario but could not reproduce it. Do you have more than one tomcat running by a chance? Have you made any custom modifications to `catalina.sh`? Any other deviations from vanilla Tomcat?

Comment: @maindas Thanks - but it's works now. Don't know why - but after few restarts works. P.S. under this user - runs only one Tomact; catalina.sh - without modifications.